# aws CLI blockd through the network

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

It appears that traffic for the AWS CLI is blocked in my network level. I would like to use a proxy server that will let the AWS traffic through, but am having difficulty finding documentation that I can use to get the proxy unblocked. Can someone please point me in the right direction to show me what ports and or websites need to be unblocked?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Mark, I have read that piece and am using that to add the proxy server, however I do not know what needs to be unblocked at the proxy level to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the problem on my own. The [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-http-proxy.html) are incorrect for setting up a proxy in the Windows environment.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=your.proxy.com
set HTTPS_PROXY=your.proxy.com
```

you don't need the http after the = sign.